# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a string, coming from HTTP. The string looks like

```
[
    {
        "apiVersion": "ocs.openshift.io/v1alpha1",
        "kind": "StorageCluster",
        "metadata": {
            "name": "example-storagecluster",
            "namespace": "openshift-storage"
        },
        "spec": {
            "manageNodes": false
        }
    },

 ]
```

Parsing this string gives this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ with JSON.parse

Can someone help me how to parse this string and get the value inside [ ]. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that HTTP response is string and not array? If not then check for http response content-type first. Or use `typeof` this value.

Answer (score 1):

The Comma after the last } is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. I executed in background script and it gives values correctly

```
var string = '[{"UserID":"10001","Name":"Ram"},{"UserID":"10002","Name":"Sultana"},{"UserID":"10003","Name":"Lakshmi"}]';


var parser = new JSONParser();
var parsedData = parser.parse(string);
var length = parsedData.length;

gs.print(length);



for(var i=0;i<length;i++){

gs.print(parsedData[i].UserID); 
gs.print(parsedData[i].Name);

}
```

Mark Correct if this solves your issue and also hit Like and Helpful if you find my response worthy based on the impact.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON document. You can always use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your documents if you don't have any other way.

In your case you have 1 comma too much in your JSON document:

```
[
    {
        "apiVersion": "ocs.openshift.io/v1alpha1",
        "kind": "StorageCluster",
        "metadata": {
            "name": "example-storagecluster",
            "namespace": "openshift-storage"
        },
        "spec": {
            "manageNodes": false
        }
    }
]
```

[image]